# Defining the Arch Linux bootloader on a Chromebook?

Tags: arch-linux, ssd, chrome-book

I'm planning on installing Arch Linux onto an Asus Chromebook Flip C100P. After enabling developer mode and [creating a compatible live USB](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/rockchip/asus-chromebook-flip-c100p), I'm ready to start partitioning the device.

Whenever I've done this in the past, I've been used to [partitioning the HDD into the boot and user regions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners'_guide#Partition_schemes) of a `/dev/sdx` device. In this instance, I'm only able to target memory devices with the prefix `/dev/mmcblkXXXX`. The device I'm using uses an SSD, which I expect to be treated no differently in this process (apart from requiring me to [enable TRIM support](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives#TRIM)), but I'm a little confused about the device entries (via `lsblk`).

```
mmcblk0boot0 (disk) 4M
mmcblk0boot1 (disk) 4M
mmcblk0      (disk) 14.7G
```

I'm unsure whether if I make a fresh Arch installation on `mmcblk0`, will the bootloader be able to detect it? What's the purpose of `mmcblk0boot0` and `mmcblk0boot1`? Is it possible I'll need to change these too? (Can they be changed at all? I'm under the impression they're distinct physical devices.)

Comment: It's occurred to me that if I follow the linked tutorial and just target `mmcblk0`, it should work fine; the exact same as it detects the USB. I'll update if this is the case.

Comment: This requires copying the static `cgpt` binary from ChomeOS.

Answer (score 1):

Leave `mmcblk0boot0` and `mmcblk0boot` unchanged, and target `mmcblk0` as you would a standard HDD exactly as the linked tutorial recommends. Using `wifi-menu`, you can get a hold of the `cgpt` libraries which you can use to configure the installation using the Arch Live USB. This achieves a `base-devel` installation of Arch Linux on the Chromebook.

Comment: Yes you should leve the boot partitions as they are, the guide is a bit confusing as it instructs to install to external USB storage, not to internal storage. Details about the [disk-format](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/disk-format) are documented at the chromium.org site. I just checked my N22 where I used chrx and it didn't touch these partitions either.